# Find difference value from two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get difference value from array and also want to compare that difference value is from which array.

First Array => Variable : $first_array

```
Array {607,608,609}
```

Second Array => Variable : $second_array

```
Array {607,608,609,610}
```

want to get output like Difference value : 610...... From Array :- $second_array

How can i get ? please help me ....

Comment: use like this    array_diff(first array variable,second array variable);

Comment: go with [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff)

Comment: array_diff not proper working.....for this array

Comment: if array_diff($second_array,$first_array) then it will give.. difference....but if array_diff($first_array,$second_array) it will give empty value

Answer (score 1):

it will work

```
<?php
$a=Array(607,608,609,610);
$b=Array (607,608,609);
$result=array_diff($a,$b);
print_r($result);
?>
```

or else try this

```
<?php
 $array2 = array(607,608,609); 
 $array1 = array(607,608,609,275); 

foreach ($array1 as $value)
{ 
  if(in_array($value, $array2)) 
     { 
       $key = array_search($value, $array2); 
       $key1 = array_search($value, $array1); 
       unset($array2[$key]); 
       unset($array1[$key1]); 
      //echo "yes<br>"; 
      } 
  } 
     $merge = array_merge($array1,$array2); 
    print_r($merge);
 ?>
```

Comment: <?php
$a=Array(607,608,609);
$b=Array (607,608,609,610);
$result=array_diff($a,$b);
print_r($result);
?>
this is not working

Comment: i want to compare programmatically...not using function...because in function i don't get perfect output

Comment: then you have to use foreach

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_diff()

```
$result=array_diff($first_array,$second_array);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$first_array=array(607,608,609);
$second_array=array(607,608,609,610);

$result=calculate_diff($second_array,$first_array);
print_r($result);

function calculate_diff($array1,$array2)
{
    $diff = [];
    $larger_array = $array2;
    $smaller_array = $array1;

    if(count($array1) > count($array2))
    {
        $larger_array = $array1;
        $smaller_array = $array2;
    }

    foreach($larger_array as $ele)
    {
        if(!in_array($ele,$smaller_array))
        {
            $diff[] = $ele;
        }
    }

    return $diff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by merging them and then using array_diff, array_diff_assoc and array_unique.
https://3v4l.org/Z1vpe

```
$first = Array(607,608,609,610);
$second = Array(800,607,608,609);
$Fcount = count($first);
$arr = array_merge($first, $second);


$arrc= array_diff($arr, array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr)));
foreach ($arrc as $key => $value){
    if($key < $Fcount){
        echo "first array ". $value . "\n";
    }else{
        echo "second array " . $value . "\n";
    }
}
```

Edited to add how to find which array the value is in.  https://3v4l.org/W7rch

Comment: how can i get from which array diiference value i got?

Comment: I suppose you can look at the key and see which it's in. In this case the var_dump returns  [3] = 610. Since the count() of $first is 4 then it's in the first array. So basically the key compared to count of first array.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
<?php
$a=Array(607,608,609,610);
$b=Array (607,608,609);
$res=array_diff($a,$b);
print_r($res); // output 610
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = array(607,608,609,610);
$b = array(607,608,609);
$c = array_diff($a,$b);
print_r($c);
```

Comment: I doubt this helps or works at all. Please convince me by explaining.

Comment: you can simply run this program. It will give output as `Array(610)`

Comment: That is a promise that you did test it and the output. I wouldl like an explanation how it works and why it solves the problem.

Comment: array_diff — Computes the difference of arrays

check more here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$a1=array(607,608,609,610);
$a2=array(607,608,609);

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);

Output :-  Array ( [3] => 610 )
```

Answer (score -2):

$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue","r"=>"black");

$d = array_merge($a1,$a2);

output:array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow","e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue","r"=>"black")

$result=array_diff($d,array_intersect($a2,$a1));

print_r($result);
output:array("d"=>"yellow","r"=>"black");

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I doubt this helps or works at all. Please convince me by explaining.

Comment: Please add ``` around your code. Like this ``` code ``` -> `code`

Comment: Please convince me by explaining how this works and why it is supposed to help. You cannot convince me by promising.

Comment: Be careful when editing, not to undo helpful formatting improvements applied by others. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: array_intersect will get matching values so will get red,green,blue     then array_diff will get different between two arrays

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to [edit] that explanation into the answer itself? You could use the opportunity to re-fix the formatting which your last edit broke.